# Link a url in flask using python function

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to link a url in Flask but can't find the solution for the problem. My idea is to search for a protein in UniProt depending on the parameters given in my webpage. The example is:

```
@app.route('/http.html')
def http():
    return render_template('http.html')

@app.route('/http_results', methods=['POST'])
def http_results():
    protname_seq = request.form['protname_seq']
    specie_seq = request.form['specie_seq']
    input_text = seqtools.httplink(protname_seq,specie_seq)
    return render_template('http_results.html', **locals())
```

In `seqtools` I have a python code with the following function:

```
def httplink(prot,specie):
    a=prot
    b='_'+specie
    c=print('http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=',a+b,'&sort=score')
    return c
```

And now in the `http_results.html` I tried multiple things but in the end the result is *None* or an error so I really don't know how to proceed. The `http_results.html` code is:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<div>
<p>The link to the protein is:</p>
<p><a href={{input_text}}>{{ protname_seq }}</a></p>
<br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Just want the name of the protein linked to the UniProt webpage. Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print` function returns `None`, thus, you need to break the `print` and assignment operations onto two separate lines:

```
c='http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query='+a+b+'&sort=score'
print(c)
return c
```

Also, you need to add quotes around the `href` in the `a` tag:

```
<p><a href='{{input_text}}'>{{ protname_seq }}</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function named `httplink`, you don't assign `c` anything. You should return the string literal inside print statement.

```
def httplink(prot, specie):
    url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=%s_%s&sort=score'
    return url % (prot, specie)
```

This function should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry for not being possible to vote you two.

Comment: heheh its okay. glad u figured things out.